# Send Event Email Reminder Javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook, gmail

Any idea on how to send an event email reminder(Outlook or Gmail) with attendees, start time, end time, start date, end date and location using Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SendGrid's JavaScript web API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail). First you'll need a [SendGrid account](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/). Then you can install their library via NPM (instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail)). Next, you'll need an array of your attendee's email addresses:

```
var attendees = [attendee1@example.com, attendee2@example.com, attendee3@example.com];
```

Then you can use the API like so:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: attendees,
  from: 'reminder@example.com',
  subject: 'You have an upcoming event!',
  text: 'Start time: ' + startTimeVariable + ' Start date: ' + startDateVariable + 
    ' End time: ' + endTimeVariable + ' End date: ' + endDateVariable + 
    ' Location: ' + locationVariable
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

Comment: How can I run it through localhost?